# Confusion about convolution. Are the integrals equivalent?

Tags: analysis, convolution

The formula for a convolution is given by

$$f*g(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t-u)g(u) \ du. \tag1$$

My question is, is the following equally correct?

$$f*g(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(u)g(t-u) du.\tag2$$

I'm asking because in my case I got

$$f(t,x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1} \quad \text{and} \quad g(t,x)=\frac{e^{-x^2/4t}}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}.\tag3$$

So I get two very different integrals.

Comment: try doing a change of variables in the integration, $v=t-u$

Comment: I suggest using different letters for the variables of integration in the two integrals:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f( t - u) \; g(u) \; du,
$$
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f( w ) \; g(t - w) \; dw.
$$
Do we obtain the second integral from the first by the variable change $u = t - w$ or any other variable change?  I doubt it.  That would explain the difference between the two integrals you are getting.

Comment: @avs - Are you concluding that $g*f \neq f*g ?$

Comment: No. [Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) is commutative.

Comment: No, the definition of $f*g$ is $f*g(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t-u)g(u) \ du$. Your notation $f*g(t,x)$ makes no sense that I can see. Similarly  saying $f(t,x)=1/(x^2+1)$ makes no sense  here - that should be $f(x)=1/(x^2+1)$ or $f(t)=1/(t^2+1)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I was wondering about the role of $x$, and I think it's part of the OP's overall source of confusion: which symbols denote which variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since we get:
$$
(f*g)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \ f(t-u)g(u) \ du = -\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} \ f(v)g(v-t) \ dv = (g*f)(t)
$$
So the convolution product is commutative.

Comment: So in my case, if I were to use $(1)$ I get $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{1+(x-u)^2}\frac{e^{-(u)^2/4t}}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} \ du.$$

But If I choose (2) I get instead $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{1+u}\frac{e^{-(x-u)/4t}}{\sqrt{4 \pi t}} \ du.$$

Are both correct?

Comment: Yes, they will both be correct because of the above, and furthermore you can switch between them by using a change of variables, the first integral is the second with $v=x-u$, although in your second integral you missed a square on the $u$ and a square on $(x-u)$ in the exponential.